# Android: Bitmap size exceeds 32 bit in DialogFragment

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview

This is not a duplicate of [Mysterious stacktrace in Android developer console (bitmap size exceeds 32bits)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9370145/mysterious-stacktrace-in-android-developer-console-bitmap-size-exceeds-32bits)

That question didn't provide a single line of code and there's no answer either; besides, I get this error even if I set the Bitmap size to 32x32, it is the only Bitmap, so it is not memory related.

**What I want to do**

1. Get the size of an ImageView,
2. create a BitMap
3. and draw something on a Canvas.

The `Log.e` output for the size of the ImageView and therefore Bitmap is:

```
Width: 272
Height: 136
```

**What happens**

The below code works well on Nexus4, Nexus7 and Desire HD (CM10), but running the app on the emulator gives me the error shown below (API 8).

**Findings**

1. I've tried it with half the size and 32x32, which gives the same error.
2. I am displaying the ImageView in a DialogFragment (ActionBarSherlock/HoloEveryWhere for API 8), maybe that's the culprit?

ImageView:

```
<ImageView
      android:id="@+id/imageView1"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="1dp"
      android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
      android:layout_marginTop="12dp" />
```

In my activity:

```
iv = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
ViewTreeObserver vto = iv.getViewTreeObserver();
vto.addOnPreDrawListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onPreDraw() {
         if (!waveFormMeasured) {
             if (iv.getMeasuredWidth() > 1) {
                 width = iv.getMeasuredWidth();
                 Log.e(TAG, "Width: " + width + " Height: " + width / 2);
                 waveBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap((int) width, (int) ((int) width / 2), Config.RGB_565);
                 Log.e(TAG, "Bitmap created");
                 waveCanvas = new Canvas(waveBitmap);
                 Log.e(TAG, "Bitmap set to Canvas");
                 iv.getLayoutParams().height = width / 2;
                 Log.e(TAG, "ImageView Height changed");
                 iv.setImageBitmap(waveBitmap);
                 Log.e(TAG, "Bitmap set to ImageView");
                 drawWaveForm(true);
                 Log.e(TAG, "WaveForm drawn");
                 waveFormMeasured = true;
              }
          }
     return true;
     }
  });
```

What is wrong here ?

```
02-21 17:12:48.301: E/Drummers(375): Width: 272 Height: 136
02-21 17:12:48.301: E/Drummers(375): Bitmap created
02-21 17:12:48.301: E/Drummers(375): Bitmap set to Canvas
02-21 17:12:48.301: E/Drummers(375): ImageView Height changed
02-21 17:12:48.301: E/Drummers(375): Bitmap set to ImageView
02-21 17:12:48.623: E/Drummers(375): WaveForm drawn
02-21 17:12:48.842: E/AndroidRuntime(375): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-21 17:12:48.842: E/AndroidRuntime(375): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: bitmap size exceeds 32bits
02-21 17:12:48.842: E/AndroidRuntime(375):  at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method)
02-21 17:12:48.842: E/AndroidRuntime(375):  at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:477)
02-21 17:12:48.842: E/AndroidRuntime(375):  at android.view.View.buildDrawingCache(View.java:6577)
02-21 17:12:48.842: E/AndroidRuntime(375):  at android.view.ViewGroup.onAnimationStart(ViewGroup.java:1259)
02-21 17:12:48.842: E/AndroidRuntime(375):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1505)
02-21 17:12:48.842: E/AndroidRuntime(375):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
02-21 17:12:48.842: E/AndroidRuntime(375):  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6883)
02-21 17:12:48.842: E/AndroidRuntime(375):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1646)
02-21 17:12:48.842: E/AndroidRuntime(375):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
02-21 17:12:48.842: E/AndroidRuntime(375):  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6986)
02-21 17:12:48.842: E/AndroidRuntime(375):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:357)
02-21 17:12:48.842: E/AndroidRuntime(375):  at android.widget.ScrollView.draw(ScrollView.java:1409)
02-21 17:12:48.842: E/AndroidRuntime(375):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1646)
02-21 17:12:48.842: E/AndroidRuntime(375):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
02-21 17:12:48.842: E/AndroidRuntime(375):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
02-21 17:12:48.842: E/AndroidRuntime(375):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
02-21 17:12:48.842: E/AndroidRuntime(375):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
02-21 17:12:48.842: E/AndroidRuntime(375):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
02-21 17:12:48.842: E/AndroidRuntime(375):  at android.view.View.buildDrawingCache(View.java:6640)
02-21 17:12:48.842: E/AndroidRuntime(375):  at android.view.ViewGroup.onAnimationStart(ViewGroup.java:1259)
02-21 17:12:48.842: E/AndroidRuntime(375):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1505)
02-21 17:12:48.842: E/AndroidRuntime(375):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
02-21 17:12:48.842: E/AndroidRuntime(375):  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6883)
02-21 17:12:48.842: E/AndroidRuntime(375):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:357)
02-21 17:12:48.842: E/AndroidRuntime(375):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:1862)
02-21 17:12:48.842: E/AndroidRuntime(375):  at android.view.ViewRoot.draw(ViewRoot.java:1522)
02-21 17:12:48.842: E/AndroidRuntime(375):  at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1258)
02-21 17:12:48.842: E/AndroidRuntime(375):  at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1859)
02-21 17:12:48.842: E/AndroidRuntime(375):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-21 17:12:48.842: E/AndroidRuntime(375):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
02-21 17:12:48.842: E/AndroidRuntime(375):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
02-21 17:12:48.842: E/AndroidRuntime(375):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-21 17:12:48.842: E/AndroidRuntime(375):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
02-21 17:12:48.842: E/AndroidRuntime(375):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
02-21 17:12:48.842: E/AndroidRuntime(375):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
02-21 17:12:48.842: E/AndroidRuntime(375):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Did you find the solutions, or even the cause of this exception ?

Comment: the stack trace suggests that the crash is not on the `waveBitmap`, but rather caused by animation start calling `buildDrawingCache()`.

Answer (score 2):

bitmaps have a size limit that depends on the device. The size is generally the size of the screen itself. There are several questions on stack overflow that address this issue, such as [OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget :- Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2928002/outofmemoryerror-bitmap-size-exceeds-vm-budget-android) or [Strange out of memory issue while loading an image to a Bitmap object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477572/android-strange-out-of-memory-issue-while-loading-an-image-to-a-bitmap-object) . If you need a very large image, you can simply break it down into more manageable sizes, and place them in multiple `ImageViews`. I created an app several months ago with a large, scrollable image that was about 15 images strung together seamlessly - validation that this is a good way to go.

On a final note, bitmaps are difficult to work with directly, due to the memory issues they cause on Android. Look into [BitmapFactory.Options](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html), and always remember to nullify and `recycle` unused bitmaps.

**Edit**

It may also have something to do with modifying the contents of the View in `onPreDraw()`. This post: [When Can I First Measure a View?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4393612/when-can-i-first-measure-a-view) discusses how editing the size of a View in this method will cause `onPreDraw()` to continually be called, whereas performing these operations with an `onGlobalLayoutListener` will give the expected results.

Comment: I am aware of all that, but the size is only 272x136 (as mentioned in my post), which is less than the screen width, since this is ImageView is shown in a DialogFragment. I dont get a Out of Memory Error, but the one mentioned above in the question.

Comment: Same error with the bitmap size set to 32x32. This is the only Bitmap I am showing, nothing else with a huge need of memory in my app.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a problem with setting a DialogFragment to match_parent (both width and height) in API 8.
I can't exactly say what is happening, but adding the following dummy layout fixed it (I had a couple of LinearLayouts/TextViews/SeekBars etc. with layout_width="match_parent" and the whole thing worked in API 11+):

```
<org.holoeverywhere.widget.ListView
     android:id="@+id/sampleList"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</org.holoeverywhere.widget.ListView>
```

The following didn't work to set it to fullscreen:

```
setStyle(...)
```

or

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```