# Crash with v7 support library - bitmap size exceeds 32bits

Tags: android, bitmap, crash, android-support-library, illegalargumentexception

I updated my App using the new v7 support library and it crashes more than ever before.
The first crash was because of some Samsung devices with Android 4.2.
Now I have a new one:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: bitmap size exceeds 32bits
>   at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method) at
>   android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:605) at
>   android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:585) at
>   android.view.View.buildDrawingCache(View.java:10768) at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2761) at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2503) at
>   android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10557) at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2864) at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2503) at
>   android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10557) at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2864) at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2503) at
>   android.view.View.draw(View.java:11123) at
>   android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:450) at
>   android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10559) at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2864) at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2503) at
>   android.view.View.draw(View.java:11123) at
>   android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.draw(RecyclerView.java:2262) at
>   android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10559) at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2864) at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2503) at
>   android.view.View.draw(View.java:11123) at
>   android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:450) at
>   android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10559) at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2864) at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2503) at
>   android.view.View.draw(View.java:11123) at
>   android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10559) at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2864) at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2503) at
>   android.view.View.draw(View.java:11123) at
>   android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:450) at
>   android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10559) at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2864) at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2503) at
>   android.view.View.draw(View.java:11123) at
>   android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.draw(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:509)
>   at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10559) at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2864) at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2503) at
>   android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10557) at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2864) at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2503) at
>   android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10557) at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2864) at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2503) at
>   android.view.View.draw(View.java:11123) at
>   android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:450) at
>   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:2276)
>   at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10559) at
>   android.view.HardwareRenderer$GlRenderer.draw(HardwareRenderer.java:876)
>   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:2092) at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1816) at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2628) at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4517) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:993)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:760) at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

This is all I have from the Google Play Developer Console. I even don't know how to reproduce this crash. My App does not use any Images!?
But can anyone tell me how to avoid this crash?

Comment: First I would try to clean the project. I think this might be answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9370145/mysterious-stacktrace-in-android-developer-console-bitmap-size-exceeds-32bits?rq=1

Comment: There is no code - there is no hint where this crash happens