# Is there a maximum bitmap size when using getDrawingCache?

Tags: android, bitmap, nullpointerexception, textview

I'm trying to create a bitmap of the text in a `TextView`. In the past I have done this using `getDrawingCache`. However, now I have a need to create a bitmap of a `TextView` with much longer text than before. This is causing `getDrawingCache` to throw a NullPointerException.

Although I say "much longer text," I am not talking about unreasonably long. If I create a TextView that is 600 pixels wide at size 24 font, I get the exception at 53 lines of text (but not at 52 lines). Is there a workaround for this?

At first I thought [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11561518/3681880), in which the layout draws itself on a `canvas`, was the solution. However, that didn't work for me because I am creating the TextView programmatically and [the width and height are 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3591784/getwidth-and-getheight-of-view-returns-0) before they get laid out. I never actually layout my `TextView` on screen.

## Code for reference

```
private Bitmap getBitmap(Context context){

    final int NUMBER_OF_LINES = 53; // 53 crashes, 52 doesn't
    final int width = 600; // width of TextView in pixels
    final int fontSize = 24;

    // create string with NUMBER_OF_LINES
    StringBuilder testString = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_LINES; i++) {
        testString.append("\n");
    }

    // Create TextView
    TextView tvText = new TextView(context);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    tvText.setTextSize(fontSize);
    tvText.setWidth(width);
    tvText.setLayoutParams(params);
    tvText.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE); // even setting the background color affects crashing or not
    tvText.setText(testString);

    // Create bitmap
    tvText.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    tvText.measure(View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
            View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
    tvText.layout(0, 0, tvText.getMeasuredWidth(), tvText.getMeasuredHeight());
    tvText.buildDrawingCache(true);
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(tvText.getDrawingCache()); // crashes here
    tvText.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);

    // This also didn't work because width and height are 0
    /*Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(tvText.getWidth(), tvText.getHeight(),
            Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    tvText.draw(canvas);*/

    return bitmap;
}
```

## NullPointerException

```
06-21 14:20:24.628    8036-8036/com.example.testsomecode E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.testsomecode/com.example.testsomecode.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2092)
        ...
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:494)
        at com.example.testsomecode.MainActivity.getBitmap(MainActivity.java:57) // -> Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(tvText.getDrawingCache());
        at com.example.testsomecode.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:25)
        ...
```

## Note

This is not an IllegalArgumentException or OutOfMemoryError (At least not externally, though maybe this is the reason internally.)

- [Mysterious stacktrace in Android developer console (bitmap size exceeds 32bits)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9370145/mysterious-stacktrace-in-android-developer-console-bitmap-size-exceeds-32bits)
- [Strange out of memory issue while loading an image to a Bitmap object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477572/strange-out-of-memory-issue-while-loading-an-image-to-a-bitmap-object)

Comment: is the textview added to some container like relative layout or linear layout?

Comment: `tvText.getDrawingCache()` returns null.

Comment: try adding your textview to a container then get the measurements of the textview. then you should be able to get the bitmap

Comment: after you call `tvText.layout()` just create a `Bitmap`, then create a `Canvas` based on that `Bitmap` and finally call `tvText.draw()`, @Raghunandan no need for adding the view to any container

Comment: @pskinkn i thought the measurements width and height was zero. any way i never though of drawing it onto the canvas

Comment: @Raghunandan still, there is no need for adding a view to a parent container: simple `layout()` will do the trick

Comment: @pskink, Calling `measure()` and `layout()` before drawing the view to canvas was the solution. Thank you very much. If you want to write that as an answer I will accept it. Otherwise, I can add the answer myself in a few days.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can drop the `buildDrawingCache` method and just use `canvas`. Since you are building the view programmatically you also need to call `measure()` and `layout()` before you can get a bitmap.

The key lines are:

```
    tvText.measure(View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
            View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
    tvText.layout(0, 0, tvText.getMeasuredWidth(), tvText.getMeasuredHeight());
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(tvText.getWidth(), tvText.getHeight(),
            Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    tvText.draw(canvas);
```

Here is the full example:

```
private Bitmap getBitmap(Context context){

    final int NUMBER_OF_LINES = 153;
    final int width = 600;
    final int fontSize = 24;

    // create string with NUMBER_OF_LINES
    StringBuilder testString = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_LINES; i++) {
        testString.append("\n");
    }

    // Create TextView
    TextView tvText = new TextView(context);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    tvText.setTextSize(fontSize);
    tvText.setWidth(width);
    tvText.setLayoutParams(params);
    tvText.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE); // even setting the background color affects crashing or not
    tvText.setText(testString);
    tvText.measure(View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
            View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
    tvText.layout(0, 0, tvText.getMeasuredWidth(), tvText.getMeasuredHeight());


    // Create the bitmap from the view
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(tvText.getWidth(), tvText.getHeight(),
            Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    tvText.draw(canvas);

    return bitmap;
}
```