# How to convert a big view to a bitmap?

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-bitmap

I need to convert large view (width and height as 1920x840) to Bitmap. I am getting **java.lang.OutOfMemoryError** exception on low end devices whose memory size less. I tried this code.

```
        setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        buildDrawingCache();
        Bitmap b = getDrawingCache();
        if (b == null) {
            int width = getLayoutParams().width;
            int height = getLayoutParams().height;
            //here i am getting out of memory exception
            b = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
            draw(c);
        }

        destroyDrawingCache();
        setDrawingCacheEnabled(false); 
        return b;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7200535/how-to-convert-views-to-bitmaps

Comment: @duggu, it is not

Comment: thats why im not close this question @VladyslavMatviienko, so i wrote possible duplicate

Comment: Form [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30961921/717341) older question (which might equate to today's "low-end" devices) it seems that the `buildDrawingCache()` is the problem.

Comment: We can scale the bitmap if we create it from resource, file or byte array. but here i need to draw whole view into the bitmap. so bitmap size should be same as a view size. Here two culprits are: getDrawingCache() returns null for big sizes and Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888); throws out of memory exception. Is there any other way to create bitmap from view?