# converting pixels array in bitmap for Android

Tags: java, android, bitmap

I have a `262144`(512*512) one dimensional pixel `int[] pixelsArray` array taht I want to convert into `Bitmap` and display it in an `Android` app, so I put

```
 bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(512, 512, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    bitmap.setPixels(pixelsArray, 0, 512, 0, 0, 512, 512);

I get this message 

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: bitmap size exceeds 32bits
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: bitmap size exceeds 32bits
            at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method)
            at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:689)
            at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:666)
            at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:633)
```

I tried some `SO` solutions, but none worked. Could someone help ?

Comment: what error did you get ?

Comment: @Blackbelt sorry error when copy pasting. Here's the log

Comment: please check this topic carefully ( the same issue ). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9370145/mysterious-stacktrace-in-android-developer-console-bitmap-size-exceeds-32bits

Comment: @Tokiroto yes I have already looked at it - but it is not my  problem since I need to create a bitmap from a pixel array and not from a path

Answer (score 1):

here's the answer that worked :

```
bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(512, 512, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
byte[] byteArray = new String(pixelsArray).getBytes("UTF-8");
BitmapFactory.Options thumbOpts = new BitmapFactory.Options();
thumbOpts.inSampleSize = 4;
bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, pixelsArray.length, thumbOpts);
```