# How to fix this weird "IllegalArgumentException: bitmap size exceeds 32 bits"

Tags: android, illegalargumentexception

This exception is showing up when a particular dialogFragment is launched. I am confused because it's not showing my any of my project classes hence I don't know how to fix this. Moreover, I am not using the `Bitmap` class in the fragment so this is really confusing.

Please do you have a solution for it?

```
09-27 12:11:47.440 4381-4381/com.ozuf.weper E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
   Process: com.ozuf.weper, PID: 4381
   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: bitmap size exceeds 32 bits
       at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method)
       at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:908)
       at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:879)
       at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:846)
       at android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable.updateMaskShaderIfNeeded(RippleDrawable.java:691)
       at android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable.drawBackgroundAndRipples(RippleDrawable.java:803)
       at android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable.draw(RippleDrawable.java:641)
       at android.view.View.getDrawableRenderNode(View.java:15867)
       at android.view.View.drawBackground(View.java:15816)
       at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15626)
       at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14568)
       at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14590)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3588)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3567)
       at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14528)
       at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14590)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3588)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3567)
       at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14528)
       at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14590)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3588)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3567)
       at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14528)
       at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14590)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3588)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3567)
       at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14528)
       at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14590)
       at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateViewTreeDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:273)
       at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateRootDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:279)
       at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.draw(ThreadedRenderer.java:318)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:2575)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:2385)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2012)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1073)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5988)
       at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
       at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
       at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550)
       at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5910)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1405)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1200)
```

Comment: set largeheap true in manifest file

Comment: @PreetikaKaur please can you explain your answer?

Comment: memory size is exceeding so sometimes for lower version devices it hard to support this much memory bits that is why we add this in manifest file android:largeHeap="true" in application tag. Try it if works then good else we ll see some other soln.

Answer (score 0):

Try to analyze your application with HierarchyViewer and you should analyze memory in your application. I think you just have leaks.

Comment: Like I wrote in my question, I am not using the `Bitmap` class. Thanks for your answer but it doesn't solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

in your **AndroidManifest** file under **application** tag use this

> android:largeHeap="true"

Comment: Please it is not as if I am doubting your knowledge in this answer but please can you explain to me how you got to know that it's memory leak? If it's memory leak,shouldn't it show OOM Exception?

Comment: this error is well explained at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9370145/mysterious-stacktrace-in-android-developer-console-bitmap-size-exceeds-32bits