# IllegalArgumentException with Bitmap.nativeCreate

Tags: android, exception, bitmap

I recently published an app on the Google Play Store and I have one user who encounter this exception (with an itel it1702) :

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
  at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate (Native Method)
  at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap (Bitmap.java:815)
  at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap (Bitmap.java:792)
  at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap (Bitmap.java:759)
  at android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable.updateMaskShaderIfNeeded (RippleDrawable.java:685)
  at android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable.drawBackgroundAndRipples (RippleDrawable.java:795)
  at android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable.draw (RippleDrawable.java:636)
  at android.view.View.getDrawableRenderNode (View.java:15478)
  at android.view.View.drawBackground (View.java:15427)
  at android.view.View.draw (View.java:15237)
  at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty (View.java:14182)
  at android.view.View.getDisplayList (View.java:14204)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList (ViewGroup.java:3437)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList (ViewGroup.java:3416)
  at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty (View.java:14142)
  at android.view.View.getDisplayList (View.java:14204)
  // ...
  at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateViewTreeDisplayList (ThreadedRenderer.java:273)
  at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateRootDisplayList (ThreadedRenderer.java:279)
  at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.draw (ThreadedRenderer.java:318)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw (ViewRootImpl.java:2530)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw (ViewRootImpl.java:2352)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals (ViewRootImpl.java:1982)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal (ViewRootImpl.java:1061)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run (ViewRootImpl.java:5895)
  at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run (Choreographer.java:767)
  at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks (Choreographer.java:580)
  at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame (Choreographer.java:550)
  at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run (Choreographer.java:753)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:739)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:95)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:135)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5345)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:372)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:947)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:742)
```

My app package does not appear in it so I don't know what to do. I've already checked [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39723428/how-to-fix-this-weird-illegalargumentexception-bitmap-size-exceeds-32-bits) but I don't have the `bitmap size exceeds 32 bits` message.

Thanks for your help !